# Peek n' Pop animation on custom force touch gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation

Is there a way to ask my UITableView to blur it's content except for one cell?

I'm building a custom force touch gesture recognizer, and it will show a view when force value is high enough. Problem is, I wanted to show some feedback when the force isn't enough to trigger it, so I wanted to somehow call that same animation from Peek n Pop. Is that possible?

edit:
I want to simulate this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/Art/preview_available_2_2x.png

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you are wanting to use `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`, which will require you to implement this method:

**Swift**

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, 
        viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext
              viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location
```

These will allow you to return a `UIViewController` that gets pushed when the force becomes great enough to commit the returned `UIViewController`. Setting the `sourceRect` property on `previewingContext` will allow you to do what you want:

```
previewingContext.sourceRect = someRect
```

You would set `sourceRect` to the desired `UITableViewCell`'s frame. This will make `sourceRect` the 'focus' of the entire view while everything else becomes blurred.

**Sources:**

1. [UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate/previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation)
2. [UIKit Peek and Pop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html)
3. [Objective-C tutorial for the effect](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/3d-touch-peek-and-pop/)

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Already implemented. But I don't want to use Apple's Peek n Pop, as I don't have anything to present in the "Peek". I want to use Peek animation but without having to present a preview view controller understand?